# Vector to a matrix where the next row starts 1 observation

Tags: r, matrix, transform, multiple-columns, rows

Suppose I have a data set with 40 observations

```
y <- rnorm(40,10,10)
```

Now I would like to transform this vector into a matrix with 4 observations in each row.
On top of that, I would like the row to start with value y[i] and add one each iteration upuntil the 40th observation.
So for example:

```
r1 = y[1] y[2] y[3] y[4]
r2 = y[2] y[3] y[4] y[5]
r3 = y[3] y[4] y[5] y[6]
.
.
r40 = y[39] y[38] y[37] y[36]
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: If you add one number to each row, than you are finished with for columns in row 37. Why is the directions changing in the given row 40?

Comment: Row 38 to 40 will have missing values since there are only 40 values. If you have 40 observations you can only produce 37 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `matrix` like:

```
y <- 1:40
matrix(y, 41, 4)[1:37,]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4
# [2,]    2    3    4    5
# [3,]    3    4    5    6
#...
#[35,]   35   36   37   38
#[36,]   36   37   38   39
#[37,]   37   38   39   40
```

Or using `seq` in `mapply` and fill the index matrix with the values of `y`.

```
i <- 1:37
M <- t(mapply(seq, i, i+3))
M
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4
# [2,]    2    3    4    5
# [3,]    3    4    5    6
#...
#[35,]   35   36   37   38
#[36,]   36   37   38   39
#[37,]   37   38   39   40

M[] <- y[M]
```

Comment: I find the second option extremely useful. I have one more question. Is it also possible to have the same matrix but with for example 4 3 2 1  instead of 1 2 3 4. I have not yet figured out how to do this

Comment: I have found a solution to this. use l <-t(mapply(seq, y, y+3)) and afterwards. cbind(l[,4],l[,3],l[,2],l[,1]) which is also of a matrix class

Comment: Yes that will work. An alternative to that might be: `i <- 4:40; t(mapply(seq, i, i-3))`

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to produce the first 37 rows. If you want to change the direction for the last 3 rows, then it would be easy to do with the same code:

```
purrr::map(seq_len(37), ~y[.x:(.x+3)]) %>% 
    unlist() %>% 
    matrix(nrow = 37, byrow = T)
```

Only difference would be to first save the values of the first 37 rows, then produce the last 3 rows, bind them, and turn that vector to a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Try `embed`

```
embed(y, 4)[, 4:1]
```

which could give the desired output